# Unable to integrate slick-carousel in a demo

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Slick integration for a straight-forward carousel implementation is not working. See code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".testimonial").slick();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="testimonial">
  First testimonial
</div>
<div class="testimonial">
  Second testimonial
</div>
<div class="testimonial">
  Third testimonial
</div>
```

Also available in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-nash-3b6es)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the ***CSS*** and ***theme*** file required by **Slick** to set up the demo you are using .
Either you can download files locally and then link to it or more simply link using the *CDN* for them.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"
/>
```

And second thing is you need to initiate the carousel on *Parent element* instead of  each individual items.

```
<div class="testimonial">
    <div> First Item </div>
    <div> Second Item </div>
     ... 
    </div> nth Item </div>
</div>
```

```html
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"
    />
    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="">
            First testimonial
        </div>
        <div class="">
            Second testimonial
        </div>
        <div class="">
            Third testimonial
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".testimonial").slick();
      });
    </script>
```